# Corridor with a dead body turns out to be in a Möbius strip

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, mathematics

I'm looking for a book of science fiction short stories. One of the stories describes the experiences of a man who finds himself in a corridor with a dead body. The corridor turns out to be a Möbius strip. I must have read that late 1970s.

Comment: I know that story. I think it's from van Vogt, but it's definitely an older one from the 50s or so. A man wakes up to find himself in a triangular corridor; as he walks along it, he finds a dead body laid out in his path. He goes past it, and a little while later finds another body, this one crumpled in a heap. He eventually figures out that the whole corridor is a mobius strip, with down based on whichever wall he's walking on, so the body had fallen from one wall to what became the floor. It's all part of a recruitment test for some top secret organisation.

Comment: (And a half hour of googling didn't turn up anything of us, though hopefully there's enough extra information there to point someone else in the right direction)

Comment: Yes, I recognize it as well.  But haven't been able to narrow it down.

Comment: @andrewsi Yes, that's the story. I must have read that late 1970s.

Comment: A number of stories featuring Moebius strips are discussed at http://www.carliner-remes.com/jacob/math/project/lit.htm, however I don't think any are what you are looking for.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ah-ha!

The story you're looking for is Theodore Sturgeon's "What Dead Men Tell".

It's collected in The Perfect Host, and at least some pages of it are available on [google books](https://books.google.ca/books?id=_rjZqRaVk3sC&lpg=PR14&ots=ME8Cwm0hIO&dq=theodore%20sturgeon%20%22the%20perfect%20host%22%20contents&pg=PA324#v=onepage&q&f=false)

The protaganist wakes up in a triangular corridor; as he explores, he discovers a body that has been laid out in his path, and notices that the colours of the walls and his clothing change as he walks along. The whole thing is a recruitment test, to work out if he's smart enough to join a top secret organisation.

Since you're after a collection of short stories, [here are the places where it's been anthologised](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?56166)

Comment: Good job!  Didn't recognize it as Sturgeon at all!