# SF short story about a man trapped in torus with triangular cross-section

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-gravity

This story was in an anthology, maybe one of Fadiman's (I thought it was "Fantasia Mathematica" but it's not). Dates back to the 50s, probably.

Comment: https://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/search.php?go=yes&medium=ss&orderby=title - Lotsa torus and maths related stories listed here.

Comment: What happens in the story?  Why the artificial gravity tag?

Comment: @Valorum Yep, it's listed at Kasman's mathematical fiction site: https://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/mfview.php?callnumber=mf268

Answer (score 11, accepted):

["What Dead Men Tell"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56166), a novelette by [Theodore Sturgeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Sturgeon) which was also the answer to the question [Corridor with a dead body turns out to be in a Möbius strip](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97548); first published in [*Astounding Science Fiction*, November 1949](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57622+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v44n03_1949-11_cape1736/page/n121/mode/2up). You may have read it in one of [these compilations](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?56166), most likely in [*Imagination Unlimited*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?17843) ([E. F. Bleiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._F._Bleiler) and [T. E. Dikty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T._E._Dikty), eds.).

Torus with triangular cross-section:

> "If you take a piece of clay and make a long . . . uh . . . sausage out of it, and then form it so it has a triangular cross section; and then if you bring the ends together and rotate one one hundred twenty degrees and stick 'em together, you'd have a figure like that. It would have only one side, like the . . . what was it? . . . Mobius strip."

Artificial gravity:

> With a conscious effort he opened his imaginative faculty. He had read fantasies in which antigravity and gravity-controlling devices had been used. Suppose his corridor really was circular—but vertically, like an automobile tire? And suppose, at its hub, was an artificial gravity device. Would he not then walk in a straight line, turning neither to right nor left, and then come back to his starting point? Such a fantastic device would have to compensate for the Earth constant, of course, but if he could imagine a gravity generator, a gravity insulator was no problem.

Comment: Nice! Sturgeon's titles are completely unhelpful.

Comment: @OrganicMarble To be fair, so are most sci-fi titles. Even the masters like Asimov and Clarke had strange, ambiguous titles. Can't get much more generic than "The City and the Stars" or "The stars, like dust".

Comment: Helaman Ferguson has a monumental bronze sculpture on the Stony Brook campus - it's a torus like this one (but no autonomous gravity). That shape occurs as an algebraic surface: link to the equations here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helaman_Ferguson)